# Finding the normal divisor of a random variable

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, convolution

I have an iid sample $x_1, ..., x_n$ from a random variable $X$ which itself is a convolution $X = Z + \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$. Neither distribution of $Z$ nor parameter $\sigma^2$ are known (we only assume that $Z$ has no normal divisors). My question is: how can I estimate this $\sigma^2$ based on the sample?

Of course, I could try to run the deconvolution procedure for different values of $\sigma^2$, and see for which sigmas the procedure works or fails -- but this looks like a terribly inefficient approach. After all, I don't even need the distribution of $Z$, only the value of the parameter $\sigma^2$.

If you guys ever heard of a research on this topic, I would appreciate any reference (even an obscure one).

Comment: If there is no constraint on $Z$, then what makes a certain $\sigma$ "work or fail"?

Comment: @GeoMatt22 there is a notion of decomposability of distributions (e.g. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indecomposable_distribution). Intuitively, convolving some Z with a normal distributions makes a "smoothed" distribution X. By removing a normal distribution from X, you reduce its smoothness, which cannot be done indefinitely. Thus there always has to be a "maximal normal divisor" of X.

Comment: @Pasha That's difficult to square with the infinite divisibility of Normal distributions!  In the present instance, suppose $Z$ and the additive term are both standard Normal, so that $X$ is Normal with variance $2.$  The value of $\sigma^2$ could be *anything* in the interval $[0,2].$